# Spring 4 MVC + security issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have been working with spring MVC app. Going to add security. All works correct.

according to the doc
http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#abstractsecuritywebapplicationinitializer-with-spring-mvc

added next implementation.

1. MessageSecurityWebApplicationInitializer
2. MessageWebApplicationInitializer
3. SecurityConfig

login form works.

After success authorization, have got - **HTTP Status 404 -**

Also I can debug method into appController after authorization, I mean next method `public String listPatients(ModelMap model)` .

Why I have got 404 ? what should I fix ?

```
public class MessageSecurityWebApplicationInitializer
        extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
}


public class MessageWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{AppConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{AppConfig.class};
    }


    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] {"/*"};
    }

}

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("user").roles("USER");
    }

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
    }

}

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class AppController {

    public static final String jsonPage = "json";
    @RequestMapping(value = {"/"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listPatients(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("json", "test"}");
        return jsonPage;
    }
```

BR!

Comment: I'd recommend turning on logging with Spring security + Spring MVC and see what it's doing.

Comment: For starters stop loading your application twice. Your `AppConfig` is loading the `AppConfig` for both the root and servlet context, effectively duplicating your whole application. Split your configuration in the root (services, repositories, infrastructure) and the servlet context (web related things like controllers etc).

Comment: I agree with @M.Deinum. If you check the logs at startup, you can see that you are creating two contexts. Don't do that and split your configs (check my answer below)

Comment: Maybe that's a typo, but shouldn't this sign "}" be deleted here "model.addAttribute("json", "test"}");" ?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have (working):

AppInitializer

```
public class AppInitializer extends
        AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] {
                SpringRootConfig.class,
                DatabaseConfig.class,
                SecurityConfig.class,
                SecurityInitializer.class,
                WsdlMarshallerConfig.class
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { SpringWebConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

}
```

SecurityInitializer

```
public class SecurityInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
}
```

SecurityConfig

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        auth
            .jdbcAuthentication()
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                    .usersByUsernameQuery("SELECT username, password, enabled FROM users WHERE username = ?")
                    .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("SELECT username, role FROM user_roles WHERE username = ?");
        // @formatter:on
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .and()
            .csrf()
                .disable();
        // @formatter:on
    }

}
```